# Is it possible to assign the windows as slave to the Unix Master in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to assign the windows as slave to the Unix Master in Jenkins? IF yes can u please give the steps?

Comment: Yes, a Jenkins master running on Unix can control Windows slaves. Just follow the steps in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines.